# Using a syntax macro inside of itself in Racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Apologies if this has been asked before - I'm trying to build a macro similar to `struct` and I'm a bit stuck.

The basic idea is to be able to provide a hash object to my syntax rule that should then write getters and setters for every key in the hash. For example:

```lisp
(hasheq 'name (hasheq 'S "user")
        'isOnline (hasheq 'B #t)
        'bio (hasheq 'M (hasheq 'firstName (hasheq 'S "Sally")
                                'lastName (hasheq 'S "Wallace"))))
```

Calling my macro:

```lisp
(dynamo-model-make-accessors user <my-hash-object>)
```

Should result in the following generated methods:

```lisp
user-name
user-isOnline
user-bio
user-bio-firstName
user-bio-lastName
```

This is what I have so far.

```lisp
(define-syntax (dynamo-model-make-accessors stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
        [(_ prefix fields)
            #`(begin
                    #,@(for/list ([kv (hash->list (eval (syntax->datum #'fields)))])
                            (with-syntax* ([key (car kv)]
                                               [getter (format-id #'prefix "~a-~a" #'prefix #'key)]
                                                [type (car (hash-keys (cdr kv)))])
                                    (displayln #'getter)
                                    (if (eq? (syntax->datum #'type) 'M)
                                        (dynamo-model-make-accessors #'prefix (hash-ref (cdr kv) 'M))
                                        #`(define (getter O)
                                            (+ 1 1))))))]))
```

The problem comes in when I try to interpret the nested map. I try to call my syntax rule within itself and I get:

```
dynamo-model-make-accessors: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

How can I recursively call my macro?

EDIT (newest code):

```
(define-syntax (dynamo-model-make-accessors stx)
    (syntax-parse stx
        [(_dynamo-model-make-accessors prefix fields)
            (define exprs (for/list ([kv (hash->list (eval #'fields))])
                                    (with-syntax* ([key (car kv)]
                                                       [getter (format-id #'prefix "~a-~a" (eval #'prefix) #'key)]
                                                        [type (car (hash-keys (cdr kv)))]
                                                        [value (hash-ref (cdr kv) (syntax->datum #'type))])
                                        (displayln #'getter)
                                        (displayln #'type)
                                        (if (eq? (syntax->datum #'type) 'M)
                                            #`(dynamo-model-make-accessors #'getter value)
                                            #`(define (getter O)
                                                (+ 1 1))))))
            (with-syntax ([(expr ...) exprs])
                #'(begin expr ...))]))
```

Comment: Question: in `(dynamo-model-make-accessors user <my-hash-object>)`, is `<my-hash-object>` a literal? Macro works by computing on static information. If `<my-hash-object>` is a literal, it's actually quite easy to do what you want. However, if `<my-hash-object>` is an expression that will only be apparent after evaluation at runtime, then there's no hope for macro to do this (due to the phase system @soegaard mentioned below).

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase It is an expression that gets evaluated within the macro (hence `eval`). I am curious however, how can I build a hashmap as a literal? Doesn't it need to be evaluated at some point?

Comment: `#hash([a . 1])` is a hash-table literal that evaluates to itself, just as `"foo"` is a string literal that evaluates to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally a comment, but ran out of space:

I won't rule out the possibility that one can cheat the system, but ... .

The macro system uses phases. At compile time (could be tuesday) the system has one set of bindings. When the program is compiled the bindings/values used during compilation are gone. Then at runtime (could be wednesday) the resulting program is run.

But it is a bit more complicated. If at compile time you use a macro, then your compile time program needs to be compiled first (at compile-compile-time). A macro `foo` can therefore not use `foo` - because in order to use `foo`, `foo` needs to be compiled - and to do that `foo` needs to be compiled - and ...

What you can do, is to expand into a use of `foo`.
That is you can expand into something that uses `foo`.
When `foo` returns a syntax object as a result, the expander takes
the result and continues to expand it. When the expander sees the new use of `foo`, it calls the syntax transformer associated with `foo` again.

The use of `eval` shows that you are attempting to circumvent the phases. It is an uphill battle, and it might be worth rethinking the current approach.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took your advice and expanded into a use of my own macro. Please check the edited source code above.

Comment: I agree with you that using `eval` here is wrong. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find many alternatives...I am particularly confused why sometimes I need to access pattern variables with #', sometimes they work without any reader sugar and sometimes I get it "pattern variable cannot be used outside of a template"...I've been trying to figure out why this is, but `eval` has been the easy way out so far.

Comment: A pattern variable is bound to a piece of syntax. When you create a new syntax object with `(syntax template)` aka `#'template` all occurrences of pattern variables are replaced with what they are bound to. Imagine pattern variables weren't special. Then in a template like this `#'(list x)` how can the expander know that `x` is to be replaced, but `list` is not?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write that macro in Racket. In Racket, a program's binding structure (what names are bound and what scopes they have) cannot depend on *run-time values*.

For an example of why this doesn't work, consider this example:

```
(define (get-name h obj)
  (dynamo-model-make-accessors user h)
  (user-name obj))

(get-name (hasheq 'name (hasheq 'S ___)) 'some-object)
(get-name (hasheq) 'another-object)
```

The use of `dynamo-model-make-accessors` in `get-name` must be compiled *once*. But how can it decide what names to bind when the actual *value* isn't available until the function gets called? And when it might get *multiple, different* values at run time?

Instead, you can either go more dynamic or more static.

## Dynamic

Just write a function that takes a list of symbols and does the references (and checks) at run time. So instead of `(user-bio-firstName obj)` you would write something like `(get obj '(bio firstName))`.

Then you can add a little syntactic sugar around it by making a macro (let's call it `Get` here) that adds quotes. For example:

```
(Get obj bio firstName) ==> (get obj '(bio firstName))

(define-syntax-rule (Get obj sym ...) (get obj (quote (sym ...))))
```

## Static

The other way is to make the binding structure your macro generates depend on *compile-time* information rather than *run-time* information. Here's most of one way to do it:

```
;; A RecordSpec is (Hasheq Symbol => FieldSpec)
;; A FieldSpec is one of
;; - (hasheq 'S String)
;; - (hasheq 'M RecordSpec)

;; Here we bind `user-fields` to a *compile-time* RecordSpec value
;; using `define-syntax`.

(define-syntax user-fields
  (hasheq 'name (hasheq 'S "user")
          'isOnline (hasheq 'B #t)
          'bio (hasheq 'M (hasheq 'firstName (hasheq 'S "Sally")
                                  'lastName (hasheq 'S "Wallace")))))
```

The macro can fetch the compile-time RecordSpec value associated with an identifier by calling `syntax-local-value`.

```
(define-syntax (dynamo-model-make-accessors stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ prefix spec:id)

     ;; generate-recordspec-bindings : Identifier RecordSpec
     ;;                             -> (Listof Syntax[Definition])
     (define (generate-recordspec-bindings prefix-id recordspec)
       (append*
        (for/list ([(field fieldspec) (in-hash recordspec)])
          (define field-id (format-id prefix-id "~a-~a" prefix-id field))
          (generate-fieldspec-bindings field-id fieldspec))))

     ;; generate-fieldspec-bindings : Identifier RecordSpec
     ;;                            -> (Listof Syntax[Definition])
     (define (generate-fieldspec-bindings field-id fieldspec)
       (cond [(hash-ref fieldspec 'S)
              => (lambda (string-value)
                   ;; left as exercise to reader
                   ___)]
             [(hash-ref fieldspec 'M)
              => (lambda (inner-recordspec)
                   ;; left as exercise to reader
                   ___)]))

     (define recordspec (syntax-local-value #'spec)) ;; better be a RecordSpec
     #`(begin
         #,@(generate-recordspec-bindings #'prefix recordspec))]))
```

Then you can use the macro like this:

```
(define (get-name obj)
  (dynamo-model-make-accessors user user-fields) ;; defines `user-name`, etc
  (user-name obj))
```